# Math.Random with decimal places and Code Errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

How can i get use `math.random()` to get a random number with 2 decimal places and being free to change it to 3, 4, 5 or any number?

I've tried `math.round` on a `var`, but how can I do it in a way, that everytime I call a certain function, the number of decimal cases changes?

Comment: If you want exactly 2 decimal places, get a random integer between 6000 and 6500 and then divide by 100. If you don't care about the number of decimal places, a more direct approach is possible (and indeed, easy).

Comment: Have you read how `Math.random()` works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @JohnColeman Just edited the question xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a dupetarget for this, so:

You do what John Coleman said: You generate a random number between 6000 and 6500:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 6000;
```

...and divide by 100:

```
var num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 6000) / 100;
// New bit ---------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

That gives you a number from 60 (inclusive) to 65 (exclusive) with a fractional portion that will in theory be roughly two digits, but because of the way IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (the kind of numbers JavaScript uses) works, if you output that, you may get more or fewer digits right of the decimal.

To *output* it with two digits, you use `toFixed(2)`:

```
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
```

Example:

```js
var counter = 0;
tick();
function tick() {
    var num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 6000) / 100;
    console.log(num.toFixed(2));
    if (counter++ < 100) {
        setTimeout(tick, 250);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function

```js
    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min).toFixed(2);
    }
    
    console.log(getRandomArbitrary(60, 65));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a random number between two numbers with random decimals.

```
var randomDec = function(min, max, places){
    return parseFloat(
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -1))  + min ) 
        + ( '.' + ( Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, places)) + 1))
    );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  That `(max - 1)` should be `(max - min)`.  (There should be an "edit" link under the question to let you fix it.)